# Max length of String stored with App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

When storing `String` fields with App Engine:

- What is the maximum `length()` of the `String` that App Engine
  datastore can handle?
- Also if using Objectify, is this max length the same or Objectify does some processing that affect this max length?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objectify will automatically convert Strings of more than 500 characters to native Text storage.  Be careful if you are indexing strings; Text objects are not indexed so the String > 500 chars will be unindexed.

Comment: appears a save will fail if String is >500 char and is indexed.  com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving Call Info=: At path 'notes': Request to index a value that cannot be indexed:.    Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

I think the responses to this one are out of date, so I am updating. I'm using GAE version 1.9.22 and received this in the error logs:

String properties must be **1500** bytes or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.

Using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text works well by converting the String object to Text (e.g., new Text(thisString) on the **server side** of your code. Any reference to libraries in com.google.appengine.api.datastore.* do not work on the client side. Class not found.

Answer (score 4):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types), 500 characters. And no, Objectify is a wrapper and does not modify your data, so the data size limitations are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Based on updates to Google Datastore documentation from October, 2016, here are the limits

> Maximum size of an indexed string property's UTF-8 encoding:  1,500 bytes
>
> Maximum size for an unindexed property:   1,048,487 bytes (1 MiB - 89 bytes)

So you can store strings close to 1MB in size in an unindexed `String` property.